# Dragging and dropping a card

Tags: c#

I am developing a card game which includes moving one card from one place to another.The cards are dealt/stored in picture boxes.Once the user clicks a card, I want him to be able to drag and drop the card to another picture box(this is where he wil be playing the card). I also want that when user is dragging the item that item should be stuck into the cursor.
I mean mouse cursor should have that specific card stuck to it until it's dropped.
Can any body plz help me in getting this done. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

[I answered a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931911/how-to-make-a-control-transparent-for-the-mouse-or-route-mousemove-event-to-par/931954#931954) some time ago, you may find that answer helpful. In short that solution uses the `MouseDown`, `MouseUp` and `MouseMove` events of the controls to allow them to be dragged around.